# (super) capacitor to stabilize lightweight arduino led flashlight/beeper

Tags: arduino, led, capacitor

i have set up an arduino (3.3 v) as a 48 hour beeper and led flasher for a high altitude ballon project. i successfully powered it with a button battery (3 v). now i exchanged the 20-mA-led with 250-mA-led (via transistor) and the voltage collapses with every flash (the arduino constantly restarts).

would there be a simple workaround with a (super) capacitor? what capacity would i need and how would the capacitor be connected? and what would be the energy loss? thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the duty cycle and frequency of the LED? And what is the capacity of your battery?

Comment: Coin cells are rated at ~2mA maximum continuous discharge if that. Some allow peak currents of ~10mA for short periods.

Comment: How long do you want it to run while flashing the LED?

Answer (score 1):

Coin cells are rated at ~2mA maximum continuous discharge if that. Some allow peak currents of ~10mA for short periods. It's no wonder the supply voltage drops.

A super capacitor wired up to trickle charge off the coin cell would certainly help. The capacitor would be the power supply for just the LED (not the ATMega), and you would have a resistor between the battery and capacitor to charge it at low current.

The size of the capacitor would depend on how often you plan to flash the LED, and how long the flash time is. Essentially you would need enough charge stored in the capacitor for the LED flash, but also need a long enough time between flashes to allow the capacitor to recharge. If it is a very short high intensity flash, you may find that a regular aluminium electrolytic, or tantalum capacitor would have enough capacity.